# How to change text to a png file in JS code for hiding email from spambots

Tags: javascript

I have used this method to hide email spam bots on several websites and it has been working fine, no spam. I am using text for the link to display it on the site (Contact). The website I am working on now it is a png file in my images folder for the link. How can I change the JS=code to direct it to the image so it displays on my site?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function makeLink(user,domain_begin,domain_end) {
        document.write('<a href="mailto:'+user+'@'+domain_begin+'.'+domain_end+'">Contact</a>');
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: Hi mmdavid. I don't get what you're trying to solve. Can you please elaborate, what you have (what does it looks like now) and what the desired result is?

Comment: Do you mean replace `Contact` with `<img src="my-png.png">`  if yes, then do that.  Otherwise please edit your question to explain in more detail.  You can't remove the text from the href.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to JS and this worked perfectly.